# Best Way to map table of data to typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I was lookuping for a best way to map table of enum(or interface) of data to proper place.

[image]

So I mean for example **Smoke Sensor** - **Push Button** can only access to **SS** - **PI** SYMBOL and **Smoke Sensor** - **Push Button** can only access to **000 - TTT** PARAMETER.

I wonder you know my mean.

How Can I map these.

**Edited:**

Im try to achive this via typescript:

```
export enum IName {
  SmokeSensor = 'SmokeSensor',
  GasSensor = 'GasSensor',
  MotionSensor = 'MotionSensor',
  WindowSensor = 'WindowSensor',
  Sensor = 'Sensor',
  PushButton = 'PushButton',
  Switch = 'Switch',
  Temperature = 'Temperature',
}

export enum ISymbol {
  SS = 'SS',
  SG = 'SG',
  SM = 'SM',
  SW = 'SW',
  SE = 'SE',
  PI = 'PI',
  SI = 'SI',
  TI = 'TI',
}

export enum IParameter {
  TTT = 'TTT',
  OOO = '000',
  OFF = 'OFF',
  OON = 'OON',
  POS = '0',
  NEG = '1',
}

interface IActivateSensors {
  name: Omit<IName, 'Switch' & 'Temperature'>
  symbol: Omit<ISymbol, 'SI' & 'TI'>
  parameter: Pick<IParameter, 'TTT' & '000'>
}

interface ISwitchSensor {
  name: IName.Switch
  symbol: ISymbol.SI
  parameter: Pick<IParameter, 'OFF' & 'OON'>
}

interface ITemperatureSensor {
  name: IName.Temperature
  symbol: Omit<ISymbol, 'SI' & 'TI'>
  parameter: Pick<IParameter, 'TTT' & '000'>
}

export type Sensors = IActivateSensors | ITemperatureSensor | ISwitchSensor
```

But it seems it can be done using a beter way.

Comment: I dont understand your question :o what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Suppose: SmokeSensor.Symbol.SS or SmokeSensor.Parameter.TTT How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood what you mean you can do something like this:

```js
export enum Name {
    SmokeSensor = 'SS',
    GasSensor = 'SG',
    MotionSensor = 'SM',
    WindowSensor = 'SW',
    Sensor = 'SE',
    PushSensor = 'PI',
    Switch = 'SI'
}

export interface Symbol {
    [Name.SmokeSensor]: ParameterRange;
    [Name.GasSensor]: ParameterRange;
    [Name.MotionSensor]: ParameterRange;
    [Name.WindowSensor]: ParameterRange;
    [Name.Sensor]: ParameterRange;
    [Name.PushSensor]: ParameterRange;
    [Name.Switch]: ParameterOnOff;
}

export type ParameterRange = '000' | 'TTT'; // and others
export type ParameterOnOff = 'OFF' | 'OON';

function doStuff<N extends Name>(name: N, parameter: Symbol[N]) {
    // stuff
}
```

But since `000 - TTT` is probably a range of values unless you map them all I don't see a way to do it.

---

### Edit 1

Probably the only way to achieve that is to create a const:

```js
const ParameterRange = {
    '000': '000',
    'TTT': 'TTT'
    // and others
}

const ParameterOnOff = {
    'OFF': 'OFF',
    'OON': 'OON'
}

export const Values = {
    SmokeSensor: { Symbol: { SS: 'SS' }, Parameter: ParameterRange },
    GasSensor: { Symbol: { SG: 'SG' }, Parameter: ParameterRange },
    MotionSensor: { Symbol: { SM: 'SM' }, Parameter: ParameterRange },
    WindowSensor: { Symbol: { SW: 'SW' }, Parameter: ParameterRange },
    Sensor: { Symbol: { SE: 'SE' }, Parameter: ParameterRange },
    PushSensor: { Symbol: { PI: 'PI' }, Parameter: ParameterRange },
    Switch: { Symbol: { SI: 'SI' }, Parameter: ParameterOnOff }
}

Values.SmokeSensor.Symbol.SS;
Values.Switch.Parameter.OFF;
```

This way you are forced to map every value of the range into `ParameterRange` instead of doing a value check for example.

---

### Edit 2

Using your enum, something like this?

```js
type TActivateSensors = { [Name in Exclude<IName, IName.Switch | IName.Temperature>]: { Symbol: Exclude<ISymbol, ISymbol.SI | ISymbol.TI>; Parameter: Extract<IParameter, IParameter.TTT | IParameter.OOO>; } }
type TSwitchSensor = { [Name in Extract<IName, IName.Switch>]: { Symbol: Extract<ISymbol, ISymbol.SI>; Parameter: Extract<IParameter, IParameter.OFF | IParameter.OON>; } }
type TSensors = TActivateSensors & TSwitchSensor;

export type Sensor<Name extends keyof TSensors> = {
    name: Name;
    symbol: TSensors[Name]['Symbol'];
    parameter: TSensors[Name]['Parameter'];
};

const sensor: Sensor<IName.Switch> = {
    name: IName.Switch,
    symbol: ISymbol.SI,
    parameter: IParameter.OFF
}
```

If you use `type Sensor` on an object you are forced by typescript to use only the allowed enum for each property.

Comment: Thanks fo replies , Suppose: SmokeSensor.Symbol.SS or SmokeSensor.Parameter.TTT How can I achieve this? ! According to you aswers , Can i achive this?

Comment: I marked this as answered but what if it is done with typescript, Because it can validate input argument of component(react component)

Comment: Please checkout edited section